# all the textarea disappeared in each panel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextarea

I create a JTextField array named textfied[], a Color array named mj[], and a JPanel array named jpanel[]. Then I used a for sentence to set each textarea's background and added them to a panel with the same color. but the result is confusing,all the text area disappeared expect the first one  and when I input some words into the first textfied ,it's background color appear. The flowing is my code . I'am waiting for your help!

```
 JTextArea[] jtextarea = new JTextArea[i];
         JPanel p1=new JPanel();
         JPanel p2=new JPanel();
         JPanel[] jpanel=new JPanel[i];

         for (int m=0;m<=(i-1);m++){

             jtextarea[m]=new JTextArea();
             jtextarea[m].setSize(121,194);
             jtextarea[m].setBackground(mj[m]);
             jpanel[m]=new JPanel();
             jpanel[m].setSize(127,200);

             jpanel[m].setBackground(new Color(133,242,254));
             jpanel[m].add(jtextarea[m],BorderLayout.CENTER);
             jpanel[m].setLayout(null);
```

Comment: Well, there's something fishy going on. Seeing the index `i` I assume that this loop is inside another loop and that the values are being rewritten in the second ` for (int m=0;m<=(i-1);m++){` loop. Paste the whole code please.

Comment: After you added the JTextArea to the JPanel, you then set the layout of that panel to null. Why would you do that?